# Java: What are my options for event notification in my own API?

Tags: java, multithreading, events, api

Suppose you have an API you've written that collects data **in real time** in an **independent thread**.  Data access is thread-safe and via an interface.  E.g. `getData()` which does not block and provides the latest information.  This API is used in a number of applications; some GUI driven, others console programs.

What options do you have to notify your application that there has been a data update?  We definitely do not want the API to depend on the application, so we do not want to `fireTableDataChanged()` or anything like that from the API.  (In our GUI application, we would call `fireTableDataChanged()` etc. after the API notifies us or we look at the API.)

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to write your own event producer class.

- IEventListener< EVENT >
- IEventProducer< LISTENER extends IEventListener< EVENT >, EVENT>
- EventProducer< LISTENER extends IEventListener< EVENT >, EVENT> implements IEventProducer< LISTENER, EVENT >

IEventListener is implemented by the observers. It has a method for receiving an event.

IEventProducer is implemented by any observable, via EventProducer. It has methods for adding and removing listeners.

EventProducer is thread-safe. It has a method for sending events to a CopyOnWriteArrayList of listeners. It catches and logs any exceptions thrown by listeners. It also provides methods for adding and removing listeners.

Then, any observable class can implement IEventProducer via an internal EventProducer.

If you try to support two listener types on the same class, type erasure will require that you name the add/remove listener methods differently for the different listeners.

Comment: +1 - As terrible as it sounds, I think "implement your own" is a good option here. If you are regularly adding and removing observers, the EventProducer can be optimized by modeling it after the thread safe event multicasting logic used in java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.

Comment: Edited to fix parsing of &lt;s. @Tim, I agree that "implementing your own" for such a common pattern sounds terrible. In the absence of a standard, a single in-house implementation is better than many, different per-class implementations (speaking from some unfortunate experience). I've never encountered a situation where adding/removing listeners needs to be optimized. AWTEventMulticaster pre-dates the Java concurrency package and CopyOnWriteArrayListener, which allows a simple, readable thread-safe implementation.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  How do you decide whether to implement what you have outlined or to poll the API/make `getData()` blocking?  What are the issues?

Comment: Note that it goes against Java coding guidelines to put an `I` in front of interface names.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at [Observable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and [Observer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html). I haven't used them personally, and looking at the API I'm not completely convinced I care for it. Essentially your observable data objects are forced to extend from the `Observable` class. Classes interested in the data must implement the `Observer` interface and register with the data object. This API has existed since 1.0, isn't generic, and I think it is clunky. However, this is the only Observer/Observable pattern in the Java library that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have two options.

1) Poll the API to see if it has new data.
2) Get the API to notify you when it has new data.

Getting the API to notify you can be down with the Observer pattern. Note that you don't have to use `Observable` and `Observer`, you can write your own interfaces. Basically it works as follows;

- The thing being observed (your API) has a list of observers which implement some sort of observer/listener interface. It must support observers requesting to add themselves to this list.
- The thing doing the observing/listening implements this interface and calls the API to add itself to the list of observers.
- When the thing being observed updates it's status (ie has new data) it goes through its list of observers and notifies them.

Comment: Any issues in deciding between (1) and (2)?  It looks like (2) is a whole lot more complicated than (1).  Thus, I am thinking, just make `getData()` blocking, or poll the API, where I can get away with it.